# Freeze with tkinter and other script

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, time, freeze

I have this code ,i have made a calcule script for test but time.sleep froze textfield

```
import subprocess
import tkinter as tk
from threading import Thread
import os
ospath = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
path = (ospath +"\\calcule.py")
master = tk.Tk()
master.geometry('930x450+400+400')
def sudo(cmd, terminal):

    p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, bufsize=1, universal_newlines=True, shell = True)
    p.poll()
    print("2")
    while True:
        line = p.stdout.readline()
        terminal.insert(tk.END, line)
        terminal.see(tk.END)
        if not line and p.poll is not None: break

    while True:
        print("3")
        err = p.stderr.readline()
        terminal.insert(tk.END, err)
        terminal.see(tk.END)
        if not err and p.poll is not None: break
    terminal.insert(tk.END, '\n Finished download')

textfield = tk.Text(master, font = "Arial 10", bg = "#000000", fg = "yellow")
textfield.place(x=5, y=5, width=400, height=250)

t = Thread(target = lambda: sudo(path, textfield))
t.start()

tk.mainloop()
```

and i have made an other script for test

```
import time
a = 0
b = 1
while a < 1:
    print(b)
    b += 1
    time.sleep(1)
    if b == 1000:
        a +=1
```

time.sleep freeze the code and i dont know how to debug this code.

Comment: i have try with after but i dont know how i can place